# How to make changes to /etc/profile take effect

Tags: environment-variables, profile

I am trying to change `$GRAILS_HOME` from `/usr/grails-1.3.7` to `/usr/grails-2.0.0`

If I just do `export GRAILS_HOME=/usr/grails-2.0.0` it doesn't persist when I log out and back in.

I found a line in `/etc/profile` using `grep -R "GRAILS_HOME" /etc/` which reads like

```
GRAILS_HOME=/usr/grails-1.3.7
...
export PATH ... GRAILS_HOME ...
```

So I changed that and logged out.  The change does not seem to have taken effect, although my edits to the file remain.  I cannot reboot the machine as it is serving stuff for my buddy and he is only giving me some space.  But I do want the environment variable changed permanently and everywhere.  What do I need to do?

Comment: What shell do you use?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` says `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `export GRAILS_HOME=/usr/grails-2.0.0` in /etc/profile.  If you leave off the `export` part, you're not making GRAILS_HOME persistent in the environment.

Comment: That was already in on another line.  Editing my question to make that clear.

Comment: What I would do is put an `echo $GRAILS_HOME` at the end of /etc/profile so you can both see what the variable value is at that point and verify that /etc/profile is actually being sourced when you login.

Comment: I did that and it now spits out `/usr/grails-2.0.0` when I log in but then when i type `echo $GRAILS_HOME` first thing it says `/usr/grails-1.2.2`...  Ok its also getting set in `.bash_profile`.  There we go.

Comment: The accepted is really for "What I would do..."  Nice troubleshooting idea!!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have `export GRAILS_HOME` as well. Without the `export`, `GRAILS_HOME` is only set as an internal shell variable; the `export` statement turns it into an environment variable that's visible by the processes launched by that shell. You can combine `export` with the assignment, i.e. write

```
export GRAILS_HOME='/usr/grails-2.0.0'
```

If it's not there, then `GRAILS_HOME` is being set from some other place on your system as well, and you need to go and change that. The other place may or be under `/etc` or in your account, try with another account.

If `GRAILS_HOME` is being set from `/etc/environment`, that's not a shell source file, it just looks a bit like one. But the assignments there are just `VAR="VALUE"`, there are no `export` statements.